# add string mark to log

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

a very basic question but I can't get it to work. I have this snippet of code:

```
$('.cube').each(function(i) {
    var nleft = $(this).offset().left;   
    var ntop = $(this).offset().top;
    var tbg = $(this).css('backgroundColor');       
    //output
    var cval = $('#output');
    cval.val(cval.val()+'cubes['+i+'].animate({left:'+nleft+',top:'+ntop+',backgroundColor:'+tbg+'});');
});
```

which logs me different attributes of a div-array. Problem is the background-color:

`cubes[1].animate({left:200,top:200,backgroundColor: transparent });`

this would be the log, and as you can see the `transparent` has to be in `' '` that I can use this elsewhere. Same as if the backgroundcolor would be a `#000`, it has to be with string-marks.

Comment: Replace the last part of what you have with ', backgroundColor: "' + tbg + '"});'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape the ' char in your string, like that :

```
cval.val(cval.val()+'cubes['+i+'].animate({left:'+nleft+',top:'+ntop+',backgroundColor:\''+tbg+'\'});');
```

Comment: You could have use " char to declare your string instead. If the answer is OK for you, you can accept it ! And you're welcome !